# How to implement payment intent api?

Tags: swift4, stripe-payments

So the EU changed a bunch of rules for payments and because of that I am required to use Stripes Payment API, but there is one thing that I'm stuck on. I have been using firebase functions as my backend. So the question is. what exactly is "MyAPIClient"? (see code)

```
MyAPIClient.createPaymentIntent(amount: 100, currency: "usd") {  result 
in

switch (result) {

  case .success(let clientSecret):

   // Hold onto clientSecret for Step 4

  case .failure(let error):

    // Handle the error
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyAPIClient` is a class defined in one of [Stripe's iOS examples](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Standard%20Integration/MyAPIClient.swift#L13) to handle HTTP requests between your Application and a server backend. There's a corresponding [iOS backend example](https://github.com/stripe/example-ios-backend). If you are using Firebase instead of your own server, you could define server side routes in terms of [HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

The simplest payment flow with Payment Intents will be:

1. In Firebase, setup an [HTTP endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events), where you [create](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_paymentIntent) a `PaymentIntent` and return a response, particularly the `client_secret`
2. In your app, you'll use a HTTP client to request the endpoint you created in *Step 1*. This will create a Payment Intent and return the `client_secret` to your application.
3. In your app, collect a user's [card details](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/ios#collect-card-info).
4. Via your app, and using the `client_secret` and card details you collected above, [confirm the Payment Intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/ios#handle-card-payment)

Comment: Thanks. figured away around it.

Comment: Hello, would you be so kind to write the code to add in the HTTP endpoint? I am trying to implement your 4 steps but I struggle...